# How to change text of a button but keep its UI in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I do have following code:

```
<button type="button" class="ui-button edit_ui selectLine">Line</button>
<button type="button" class="ui-button save_ui btnSaveCon">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="ui-button up_ui btnAppAgg" style="display:none;">Agree</button>
<button type="button" class="ui-button cancel_ui btnCancelCon">Cancel</button>
```

(skip)

```
if (curEmp == docDisSum) {
    if (docDisSum == docDisApp) {
        $(".btnAppAgg").html("Approve");
        $(".btnAppAgg").show();
    } else if (docDisSum == docDisAgg) {
        $(".btnAppAgg").html("Agree");
        $(".btnAppAgg").show();
    }
};
```

As you can see, the third button, .btnAppAgg is the button that would have different value as its text depends on situation.

[image]
[image]

For now, the result looks like following.

However, if I took

```
$(".btnAppAgg").html("Approve");
$(".btnAppAgg").html("Agree");
```

parts out, then it looks like following:

[image]

I tried using .text() instead of html, but it made no difference.

Is there anyway I can change the text of the button and apply ui that I defined?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really understand what your asking? *"apply ui that I defined"*? What's the question?

Comment: Could you post the CSS for the buttons?

Comment: I think a fiddle or other example of your issue would help

Comment: Jquery UI adds classes and elements behind the scenes. You should look at the resulting elements in the browser (inspect element) to determine what element to target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".btnAppAgg span").text("Approve");
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the relevant code (or a fiddle), there is one solution that may be preferable.

Instead of changing the text of the button, have two buttons and show the corresponding one:

```
<button type="button" class="ui-button up_ui btnAppAgg" data-type="agree" style="display:none;">Agree</button>
<button type="button" class="ui-button up_ui btnAppAgg" data-type="approve" style="display:none;">Approve</button>
```

Then in your JS:

```
if (curEmp == docDisSum) {
    if (docDisSum == docDisApp) {
        $(".btnAppAgg[data-type='approve']").show();
    } else if (docDisSum == docDisAgg) {
        $(".btnAppAgg[data-type='agree']").show();
    }
};
```

...or shorter:

```
if (curEmp == docDisSum) {
    $(".btnAppAgg[data-type='+ (docDisSum == docDisApp ? 'approve' : 'agree') +']").show();
};
```